# Is the Haar measure on a compact abelian group non-atomic?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $G$ be a compact abelian group with the Haar measure $\mu$. Does this measure space have an atom?

For the case $\mathbb R$, I can show that it is non-atomic. Actually, if $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ with positive measure ($m(E)>0$), we choose an $\varepsilon$ with $0<\varepsilon<m(E)$. Set $E_k=E\cap [k\varepsilon,(k+1)\varepsilon)$ for each integer $k$. Then we have $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$. Since $0\leq m(E_k)<\varepsilon$, there are at least two $E_{k_0}$ and $E_{k_1}$ with positive measure. Thus, it is non-atomic.

In general, if $E$ is a subset of $G$ with $\mu(E)>0$, then
$$\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E, K {\rm\, is\, compact} \}.$$
Then for any $\mu(E)>\delta>0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $E$ such that $\mu(K)>\mu(E)-\delta$. But I don't know how to make sure that $\mu(K)$ is strictly smaller than $\mu(E)$.

Comment: What if $G$ has only one element?

Comment: On a discrete group the measure will be atomic (specifically, a multiple of the counting measure).

Comment: If $G$ is finite, it should be atomic. If $G$ is infinite, it can't be a discrete group since it is locally compact. How about this case?

Comment: Infinite discrete spaces are locally compact

Comment: Yes, indeed. I ignore these trivial cases. So, how about the (infinite) compact abelian group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the argument given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93088/atoms-of-regular-borel-measure) if $A$ is an atom for an inner regular Borel measure $\mu$ on a LCH space, then there is $a\in A$ with $\mu(\{a\})=\mu(A)$.

Now if $G$ is an infinite locally compact nondiscrete group and $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $G$ we have $\mu\{g\}=0$ for all $g\in G$, hence there can no atoms by the above.

Comment: I think that in the second sentence you meant "infinite compact group" instead of "infinite locally compact group".

Comment: @Saucy both the result about atoms and the existence (and regularity) of the Haar measure work fine in the locally compact case

Comment: Well, something is not right, because the counting measure is a Haar measure on all discrete groups (finite or otherwise), but $\mu\{g\}=1$ for all $g$.

Comment: @Saucy yes I was assuming the group not being discrete since the asker said to avoid that trivial case, but forgot to mention it in the answer. Fixed

Comment: Looks like the True Scotsman group to me, but if you both agree what do I care.